# ошибка module 'vk' has no attribute 'Session'

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Пытаюсь написать бота для оставления комменнтариев под 1 постом с определенной задержкой.
Выдает ошибку module "'vk' has no attribute 'Session'"

```
import time, random
import vk_api
import vk
OWNID = 'айди группы'
POSTID = 'айди поста'
TOKENS = ['мой токен']
DELAY = 900
COMMENT = [
   'Яблоко',
   'Ярость',
   'кенгуру',
   'воробей',
   'жук',
   'клоун',
   'мясо',
   'ствол',
   'мох',
   'моль',
   'пуля',
   'рука',
   'кедр',
   'камень',
   'рука',
   'нога',
   'почка',
   'точка'
   
]
c = 0 # счетчик
while True:
    try:
        for TOKEN in TOKENS:
            # получение сессии и апи
            session = vk.Session(access_token = TOKEN)
            api = vk_API(session)
            if c > len(COMMENT)-1: c = 0 # сброс счетчика при выходе за границы
            api.wall.createComment(v = '11.9.9', owner_id = OWNID, post_id = POSTID, message = COMMENT[c]) # оставлен коммент
            print('+comment: ', COMMENT[c]) # лог
            c += 1 # добавить 1 к счетчику
        time.sleep(DELAY) # ждем указаное время
    except Exception as err:
        print(err)
        time.sleep(1800)
```

Answer (score 1):

В новых версиях метод был изменён

Правильно будет так:

```py
import vk_api

# Авторизация
vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token=TOKEN)

# Получение API
api = vk_session.get_api()
```